# What motivated Gödel to arithmetize syntax?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, goedel

What were the benefits of arithmetizing syntax for Gödel? What did the arithmetization of syntax allow for Gödel that was otherwise not possible?

Comment: See [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) and [Hilbert's Program](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/).

Comment: You can see the post: [understanding Gödel's 1931 paper](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484834/understanding-g%c3%b6dels-1931-paper-g%c3%b6del-numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arithmetization of syntax allows Gödel to show that statements *about* number theory are also statements *in* number theory. This allows him to construct self-referential statements about number theory in a simple way. This in turn allows him to show that Self-reference is inevitable, and that it is impossible to avoid self-reference when trying to construct complete formal axiomatic systems rich enough to describe arithmetic (And thus refuting Russell's logicist project).

There are many resource, but a good informal one which accessible to mathematicians and non-mathematicians alike is Douglas Hofstadter's "I am a Strange Loop" Chapter 10 - Gödel's Quintessential Strange Loop.

Answer (score 1):

Self reference. When a formula can be encoded by a number and also take numbers as arguments, it can also take *its own number* as an argument, allowing to formulate something like "this sentence is not provable".